# How to solve zener diode circuits

Tags: diodes, zener

Determine the range of values of Vi that will maintain the Zener diode of Fig. 7 in the “ON” state

my assumptions :

if Vz=V breakdown = 20 V then Iz will start flowing downwards and by increasing V more that 20V , Iz will grow until it reached 60mA then it goes off , shouldn't i study the case at which Iz will flow in the opposite direction ( forward bios ) ??

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's homework without any effort shown, not even an effort to write up a decent question.

Comment: What have you done to try to solve this problem?  Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: actually i tried a lot , i cant understand the idea of having constant voltage on the zener diode , and its not a homework

Comment: Izm is the max reverse current that the zener diode can pass ?

Comment: If this is not homework, perhaps you should give us some context.

Comment: i calculated the Vi at the instant of Iz=60mA reverse current and i got Vin =36.86V , if this volt increased Iz will be more than 60mA since current in 1.2k resistance is constant , will this cause diode to go OFF ?

Comment: another question in Vz= 20 V is  breakdown voltage or V gamma ?

Comment: Hint: Kirchoff's law,   Ir =  Iz + IL.  When Vz is below 20V, Iz is 0. If Iz > 60mA then zener may be damaged. The question is asking (i) what is the lowest voltage you have to put in so that the voltage across the zener is 20V (just ON)? and (ii) what is the highest voltage you can put in to give a zener current of 60mA (ON but not broken)?

Comment: then this example wont the study the case at which Iz will be directed upward ?

Comment: Please put the details that have appeared in comments into your question by editing.

Comment: Hint: this is a classic case for using a thevenin equivalent circuit.

Comment: i think the problem is solved and that's what i understood from @trevor,  at Vi=23.67V exactly , the current won't pass through the diode but once Vi>23.67V , Iz will grow until it reaches 60mA at Vi=36.87V and Vz will be 20 V all the time as long as 23.67<Vi<36.87

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reality the zener won't ...well zener, till the current gets up to the knee on the zener characteristics curve, which is a lot less then \$I_{ZM}\$. But that information is not given.

So you need to treat it as an ideal Zener.

The diode will pop at \$Vi = 36.87V\$.

Since \$I_{ZM}\$  of a zener diode is the **maximum current** that can flow through a zener diode at its rated zener voltage, VZ.

At \$20V\$ at \$I_L = 20/1200 = 16.67mA\$

So  \$I_R = 60 + 16.67 = 76.67mA\$

And \$V_i = 20 + 220 * .07667 = 20 + 16.87 = 36.87V\$

**Obviously, below 20V an ideal zener would be off.**

So it will start to hold voltage at \$V_i = 20 * (1200+220)/1200 = 23.67V\$

You could include negative Vi characteristics for completeness and maybe an extra brownie point.

Comment: So Vi is the just less than or equal 36.87 , we cant get more information than that ?

Comment: @MohamedEhab not from the data given no. You have to assume it is an ideal zener which would zener at zero current.

Comment: @MohamedEhab see my update, below 20V Vi obviously it is not going to zener...

Comment: then why did you assume that  at Vz=20V which the minimum voltage needed  , Iz will be equals 60mA which is the maximum current allowed ?

Comment: @MohamedEhab if it's an ideal zener, then at 20V on the resistor divider the zener will begin to hold the voltage.

Comment: At Vi = 23.67V Vi the zener will turn on and Iz will be infinitely small.

Comment: So at Vi=23.67V exactly , the current won't pass through the diode but once Vi>23.67V , Iz will grow until it reaches 60mA at Vi=36.87V  and Vz will be 20 V all the time as long as 23.67<Vi<36.87?

Comment: 23.67<=Vi<36.87

Comment: @MohamedEhab glad to help, I don't mind helping with homework if you learn and don't just copy and paste the answer.